# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 - React/Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

I can't sign up using my email form after entering my info. I keep on getting this error on the console.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to enter a longer password (minimum of 6 characters). The requirement wasn't made explicit in the user interface, but it is still enforced by the backend.